# How to pronounce 3:1 ratio?

Tags: pronunciation, popular-refrains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pronounce “ratio 1:1”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/how-do-i-pronounce-ratio-11)

What is the correct pronunciation of 3:1 (as a ratio)? I know this might be simple enough to be answered by any native speaker of English.

Is it "three to one ratio"? Or can I skip the word 'ratio'?

Comment: "Three to one" is indeed correct (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio)), and pretty much any word can be skipped in context. You are right that this question is too basic for this site, but you might wish to support our proposed sister site for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). Thank you.

Comment: I voted to close this as a duplicate of another question, but the non-dupe part of the question might stand on its own (Can I skip the word "ratio" in 3:1 ratio?) if you add more context.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can skip "ratio" if it is implicit.  "What is the grade of the roof?  12:1."

Answer (score 0):

You can very well skip the word 'ratio'

You can say either

> Three is to one

or

> Three to one