# 1:1 is one on one. How do you say 1:2, 1:3 and so on?

Tags: phrases

I googled it but didn't get a result.
Such as in one on one lesson.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. *1:1* is conventionally read as "one to one," not "one on one" which is a different concept. See *[How do I pronounce “ratio 1:1”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/)*

Comment: 1:1 one to one.  1:2 one to two.  1:3 one to three.  Assuming you mean ratios or proportions.

Comment: .. or odds, or probabilities, or ...

Comment: @JohnLawler Probabilities would actually be between 0 to 1, inclusive. These are odds.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, the options using colons are normally read as a ratio using the word "to" compare the numbers (i.e. **one to one**, **one to two** etc.). This is the most common usage.

Following from your wording, perhaps you are looking for such a comparison in a competitive sense (like a one on one debate for example). If such is the case, it could be read as "**one against two**" or "**one against three**" etc. This is also a common usage.